# I want to run a.sh on remote hosts and fetch all output files. output file with timestamp. I wrote below code and it is failing with error

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to run a.sh on remote hosts and fetch all output files. output file with timestamp. You can see below my ansible tasks.

```
---
   - name: 'abcd'
     hosts: 'all'
     gather_facts: 'false'
     tasks:
       - name : 'Copy the script to /tmp/ and set permission'
         copy :
           src : 'a.sh'
           dest: '/tmp'
           mode: '0700'
       - name: 'Execute the script'
         shell: >
           /tmp/a.sh
         register: 'results'
       - name: 'Display output'
         debug:
           msg: '{{ results.stdout }}'
       - name: 'Remove script'
         file:
           path: '/tmp/a.sh'
           state: 'absent'
       - name: 'fetch'
         shell: "ls /tmp/test_Prereq_*"
         register: path_files
         fetch :
          src : '/tmp/"{{item}}"'
          dest : '/home/vj/testout'
         with_items: '{{ path_files.stdout }}'
```

> ansible-playbook report_task.yml --limit

ERROR! conflicting action statements: shell, fetch

The error appears to have been in '/home/vicheruk/report_task.yml': line 24, column 8, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
     state: 'absent'
 - name: 'fetch'
   ^ here
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! You'd get an answer faster if you pay some time re-formatting your question to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your playbook is syntactically wrong. `fetch` is an module and needs to be called in its own task.

Also there is not too much sense in looping and writing in the same file. Probably you want to include `{{ item }}` in the `dest` parameter as well.

This should do the trick:

```
- name: 'register files'
  shell: "ls /tmp/test_Prereq_*"
  register: path_files
- name: fetch
  fetch:
    src: '/tmp/"{{ item }}"'
    dest: '/home/vj/testout-{{ item }}'
  with_items: '{{ path_files.stdout }}'
```

Comment: I did those changes, Ansible is not fetching files.here is message from debug mode . `"file": "/tmp/\"{'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': True, u'end': u'2018-03-11 20:21:28.160102', u'stdout': u'/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Success_20180302065814.txt\\n/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311200247.txt\\n/tmp/EM_Prereq_test0180311201454.txt\n/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311201744.txt\n/tmp/EM_Prereq_testbafffmqygx_root_Warning_20180311202123.txt",
    "msg": "the remote file does not exist, not transferring, ignored"
}`

Comment: hm, please try: `  with_items: '{{ path_files.stdout_lines }}'`